# Functional Interfaces in Scala

Tags: scala, function, traits, functional-interface

I have been working with Java for a while and now I am trying to learn Scala.
I have a hard time understanding how to create a Functional Interface in Scala. I'm trying following code, but it's not working:

```
object Ex3 extends App {

trait Printer {
  def print(s: String): Unit
}

val p: Printer = x => println(x)

p("Hello") //does not want compile, error: 'Ex3.p.type' does not take parameters
}
```

p.s. I saw this example in an online course, and it worked.

***UPD:*** I made a mistake in my code. It will work like this:

```
p.print("Hello)
```

also it works with *apply* method, as Mateusz Kubuszok said.
Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ihor! Nice to meet you there:)

`p("Hello")` - it means `p.apply("hello")`. But you didn't write `apply` method.

So you can call it like that:

```
p.print("Hello")
```

Answer (score 4):

`val p: Printer = x => println(x)` should indeed compile because `Printer` is a Single Abstract Method - its only abstract method is of signature `String => Unit` so if the compiler don't have to infer `Printer`, it can take the function that matches the method signature and add the rest.

But `p("Hello")` cannot work. To be able to call `Printer` value, it would have to have a method named `apply` defined, and there isn't one in your definition.

Answer (score 1):

We have this trait:

```
trait Printer {
  def print(s: String): Unit 
}
```

Now we can see, what happened if we try to implement it:

```
val p: Printer = new Printer {
  override def print(s: String): Unit = println(s)
}
```

We can see that our `print` method accepts one argument with the type `String`, so let's start with the function that accepts it:

```
val p: Printer = (s: String) => ???
```

And now add the implementation, we would like just print it, so let's do it:

```
val p: Printer = (s: String) => println(s)
```